# How to calculate the c_hash of the authorization code?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0

I was trying to build oauth for an application. When I get the authorization code from the authentication server, I need to verify the authorization code by comparing with the c_hash value from id_token. But, how to calculate the c_hash of the authorization code?.

Till now, I have followed the following steps but not working:

1. Calculate the hash of the authorization code.
2. Take the first half of the hash value and encode it using baseurl64

**For Example:**

Header of id_token:

```
{
  "kid": "1",
  "alg": "ES256"
}
```

Payload of id_token:

```
{
  "sub": "mahbubcseju",
  "aud": [
    "19968562382010"
  ],
  "c_hash": "xd7NpSKb8Tvs1Q2-6t-ygQ",
  "iss": "https://authserver.mahbubcseju.com",
  "exp": 1608974358,
  "iat": 1608887958,
  "nonce": "dfa2c8164652312d6736bdc0b0b037b7"
}
```

Authorization code:`'DXGp71nPXpv32QrasRjIZDFukiVVE7gk558mBtGqjjQ'`

**Code**

```
import hashlib
import base64

hash = hashlib.sha256('DXGp71nPXpv32QrasRjIZDFukiVVE7gk558mBtGqjjQ').hexdigest()
l = len(hash)
left_half = hash[:l//2]
base64_encoded = str(base64.b64encode(left_half.encode()))
```

Output: `YzVkZWNkYTUyMjliZjEzYmVjZDUwZGJlZWFkZmIyODE=`

But c_hash value and output are supposed to be equal but they are not.
What can I do ? Any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the raw bytes and not the hex representation.

```
import base64
import hashlib

hash = hashlib.sha256('DXGp71nPXpv32QrasRjIZDFukiVVE7gk558mBtGqjjQ'.encode()).digest()
left_half = hash[:len(hash)//2]
base64_encoded = str(base64.b64encode(left_half))
```

---

```
>>> base64_encoded
b'xd7NpSKb8Tvs1Q2+6t+ygQ=='
```